# Ошибка EF Core: провайдер не поддерживает 'DateOnly

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api

есть веб апи на .net 7, оно отлично запускается все миграции проходят корректно. Пишу интеграционные тесты для данного апи, для интеграционных тестов должна создаваться отдельная бд не в оперативной памяти:

ApiWebApplicationFactory:

```
using Api;
using Infrastructure.Database;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace TestsApi.Common
{
    public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
        public AccountinglocusContext DbContext { get; private set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
            {
                Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("integrationsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                config.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
            });

            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => 
            {              
                var dbContextDescriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d =>
                            d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<AccountinglocusContext>));

                services.Remove(dbContextDescriptor);

                var dbConnectionDescriptor = services
                    .SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbConnection));

                services.Remove(dbConnectionDescriptor);

                ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrTest");
                services.AddDbContext<AccountinglocusContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString));

                var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
                DbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AccountinglocusContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

integrationsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionStrTest": "Data Source=(Localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=Integration;Integrated Security=True"
  }
}
```

При запуске тестов получаю следующую ошибку:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "The 'DateOnly' property 'VatPeriod.FromDate' could not be mapped to the database type 'date' because the database provider does not support mapping 'DateOnly' properties to 'date' columns. Consider mapping to a different database type or converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-value-converters for more information. Alternately, exclude the property from the model using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данная ошибка появляется только при запуске тестов, запуск апи происходит без ошибок.

Можно сказать что данная ошибка возникает из-за типа DateOnly, но почему тогда только при запуске тестов?

Ошибку выше исправить смог добавив конвертер типа DateOnly:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

namespace Infrastructure.Helpers
{
    public class DateOnlyConverter : ValueConverter<DateOnly, DateTime>
    {
        public DateOnlyConverter() : base(
            d => d.ToDateTime(TimeOnly.MinValue),
            d => DateOnly.FromDateTime(d))
        { }
    }   
}
```

```
using Infrastructure.Helpers;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using System.Data;

namespace Infrastructure.Database
{
    public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        private IDbContextTransaction? _currentTransaction;

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Properties<DateOnly>()
                .HaveConversion<DateOnlyConverter>();
        }
    }
}
```

Но теперь появилась новая ошибка:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "The current provider doesn't have a store type mapping for properties of type 'DateOnly'."
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как решить данную проблему, почему она возникает только в тестах.

*Если нужно больше информации - пишите*

Answer (score 0):

После установки [пакета NuGet ErikEJ](https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2023/09/03/efcore-dateonly-timeonly.html), все стало работать корректно.
спасибо за помощь [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)